Using an initializer list to init a vector
I can not figure out why it does not allow me to directly initialize a vector using the following syntax:
stl::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
I have implemented from scratch both the vector and the initializer list classes.
The vector constructor (there is also a default constructor which just sets everything to 0):
vector(initializer_list<T> init) : m_capacity(init.size()), m_size(m_capacity), m_data(nullptr)
{
 this->m_data = (T *)malloc(m_size * sizeof(T));

 if (this->m_data == nullptr)
      throw "malloc: Couldn't allocate memory!\n";

 memcpy(m_data, init.begin(), m_size * sizeof(T));
}

This is my initializer_list class:
    template <typename T> class initializer_list 
    {
    public:
        typedef const T* const_iterator;
        typedef       T* iterator;

    private:
        iterator m_begin;
        size_t   m_size;

        constexpr initializer_list(const_iterator it, size_t size) noexcept : m_begin(it), m_size(size) { }

    public:
        constexpr initializer_list() noexcept : m_begin(nullptr), m_size(0) { }

        constexpr const_iterator begin() const { return m_begin; }

        constexpr const_iterator begin(initializer_list<T> init) noexcept { return init.begin(); }

        constexpr const_iterator end() const { return m_begin + m_size; }

        constexpr const_iterator end(initializer_list<T> init) noexcept { return init.end(); }

        constexpr size_t size() const { return m_size; }
    };

I created a separate constructor in the vector class which takes a initializer list as parameter. However I get the following error:
no instance of constructor "stl::vector<T>::vector [with T=int]" matches the argument list

It doesn't work because initializer lists are specified to use std::initializer_list, not your own implementation of them.

Not to mention that your own initializer list doesn't really have any storage for the data it should wrap, or a way to get the needed data from anywhere. What is your actual assignment? What is the underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think you need to implement your own variants of the standard containers?

And to nitpick a bit, "STL" is the Standard Template Library which was an inspiration for the first standard library. But STL is not the same as the standard library.

This is not a [mcve]. Always post code that reproduces the issue/error you're claiming. There is no stl::vector but std::vector. You're most probably having a namespace strl with your own vector. So post actual/real code instead of cut-out snippets of your code.

How come std::initializer_list is allowed to not specify size AND be stack allocated at the same time?

std::initializer_list is a magic type that can't be implemented by user code.
The special behavior of overload resolution and braced initializer lists work only specifically for that magic std::initializer_list type.
You can't define your own initializer_list and hope for it to work like std::initializer_list.
You also can't make the stl::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3}; syntax work without using std::intializer_list. There is no way around using it. The syntax can't be achieved in any other way.
The standard library has a lot of these magic types and functions btw. Some of them are simply unimplementable by user code and need to rely on compiler builtins instead. But some, such as std::initializer_list, also have special meaning to the compiler itself and couldn't even be replicated using the compiler's builtins.
